# Mongodb - save image as bytes or as files

Tags: mongodb

I'm developing a website which allows the user to upload an image per item. I guess there will be hundreds per user.

What is more preferred?

Save the images:

- as bytes in the DB (mongodb)
- as files in the server

I don`t really know where to place this question in the "Stack Exchange" forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People have tested data vs. file storage for this sort of thing (you can see the full details of a test [here](https://github.com/feifangit/MongoDB-GridFS-test).

Per this test, for performance reasons, the file system is the best option for production.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB will happily store binary data such as files, using its [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) system. That way you can keep the images and other user data together in one place, which is an advantage over storing the images on the file server.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually choose to store the images on the server for easier sharing which came later in the customer requests